# D3 v4 Parallel Coordinate Plot Brush Selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The parallel coordinate plot we are using and the data for the plot can be found [here](https://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/1341281). This parallel coordinate plot does not work with version 4 of d3. We have made changes based on the API changes from v3 to v4. I think the main issue is in the brush function shown below.

```
function brush() {
    let actives = dimensions.filter(function (p) {
        return d3.brushSelection(y[p]) !== null;
    });

    console.log(actives);
    let extents = actives.map(function (p) {
            return d3.brushSelection(y[p]);
    });

    foreground.style("display", function (d) {
        return actives.every(function (p, i) {
            return extents[i][0] <= d[p] && d[p] <= extents[i][1];
        }) ? null : "none";
    });
}
```

The log shows "Array []" for actives. Currently we set each dimensions brush extent to be [[-8,0],[8,height]], which may be an issue as well. The full code is provided below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
svg {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.background path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ddd;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.foreground path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: steelblue;
}

.brush .extent {
    fill-opacity: .3;
    stroke: #fff;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis line,
.axis path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis text {
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0       #fff;
    cursor: move;
}
</style>
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
let margin = {top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

let x = d3.scalePoint().range([0, width]).padding(1),
    y = {},
    dragging = {};

let line = d3.line(),
    axis = d3.axisLeft(), //Argument for axisLeft? Compare to code on original plot
    background,
    foreground;

let svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("cars.csv", function (error, cars) {

    // Extract the list of dimensions and create a scale for each.
    x.domain(dimensions = d3.keys(cars[0]).filter(function (d) {
        return d !== "name" && (y[d] = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain(d3.extent(cars, function (p) {
                return +p[d];
            }))
            .range([height, 0]));
    }));

    // Add grey background lines for context.
    background = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "background")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(cars)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", path);

    // Add blue foreground lines for focus.
    foreground = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "foreground")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(cars)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", path);

    // Add a group element for each dimension.
    let g = svg.selectAll(".dimension")
        .data(dimensions)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "dimension")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + x(d) + ")";
        })
        .call(d3.drag()
            .subject(function (d) {
                return {x: x(d)};
            })
            .on("start", function (d) {
                dragging[d] = x(d);
                background.attr("visibility", "hidden");
            })
            .on("drag", function (d) {
                dragging[d] = Math.min(width, Math.max(0, d3.event.x));
                foreground.attr("d", path);
                dimensions.sort(function (a, b) {
                    return position(a) - position(b);
                });
                x.domain(dimensions);
                g.attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + position(d) + ")";
                })
            })
            .on("end", function (d) {
                delete dragging[d];
                transition(d3.select(this)).attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d) + ")");
                transition(foreground).attr("d", path);
                background
                    .attr("d", path)
                    .transition()
                    .delay(500)
                    .duration(0)
                    .attr("visibility", null);
            }));

    // Add an axis and title.
    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .each(function (d) {
            d3.select(this).call(axis.scale(y[d]));
        })
        .append("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("y", -9)
        .text(function (d) {
            return d;
        });

    // Add and store a brush for each axis.
    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "brush")
        .each(function (d) {
            d3.select(this).call(y[d].brush = d3.brushY().extent([[-8,0],[8,height]]).on("start", brushstart).on("brush", brush));
                      })
        .selectAll("rect")
        .attr("x", -8)
        .attr("width", 16);
});

function position(d) {
    let v = dragging[d];
    return v == null ? x(d) : v;
}

function transition(g) {
    return g.transition().duration(500);
}

// Returns the path for a given data point.
function path(d) {
    return line(dimensions.map(function (p) {
        return [position(p), y[p](d[p])];
    }));
}

function brushstart() {
    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
}

// Handles a brush event, toggling the display of foreground lines.
function brush() {
    //return !y[p].brush.empty was the original return value.

    let actives = dimensions.filter(function (p) {
        return d3.brushSelection(y[p]) !== null;
    });

    console.log(actives);
    let extents = actives.map(function (p) {
            return d3.brushSelection(y[p]);
    });

    foreground.style("display", function (d) {
        return actives.every(function (p, i) {
            return extents[i][0] <= d[p] && d[p] <= extents[i][1];
        }) ? null : "none";
    });
}
</script>
```

If anyone is familiar with d3 and could offer any guidance it would be greatly appreciated. We also tried using d3.event.selection and y[p].brush.selection in the brush function.

Comment: What do you man by the plot not working? Does it draw the plot at all? Is it giving you any errors?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon the exact same issue but managed to resolve it after below changes.

Add brush for each axis this way:

```
y[d] = d3.scaleLinear().domain(d3.extent(data, function(p) {
  return +p[d];
})).range([height, 0]);
y[d].brush = d3.brushY()
  .extent([[-8, y[d].range()[1]], [8, y[d].range()[0]]])
  .on('brush', brush);
```

Subsequently, give above as the brush callback when adding the brush group:

```
g.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'brush')
  .each(function(d) {
    d3.select(this).call(y[d].brush);
  })
  .selectAll('rect')
  .attr('x', -8)
  .attr('width', 16);
```

Finally, change the brush handler to be:

```
function brush() {
  const actives = [];
  // filter brushed extents
  svg.selectAll('.brush')
    .filter(function(d): any {
      return d3.brushSelection(this as any);
    })
    .each(function(d) {
      actives.push({
        dimension: d,
        extent: d3.brushSelection(this as any)
      });
    });
  // set un-brushed foreground line disappear
  foreground.style('display', function(d) {
    return actives.every(function(active) {
      const dim = active.dimension;
      return active.extent[0] <= y[dim](d[dim]) && y[dim](d[dim]) <= active.extent[1];
    }) ? null : 'none';
  });
}
```

If above is confusing, see this standalone example that helped me with correctly brushing on parallel coordinates with d3 v4 : https://gist.github.com/kotomiDu/d1fd0fe9397db41f5f8ce1bfb92ad20d